# Нужна помощь по pyautogui и keyboard

Tags: python, клавиатура, pyautogui, sys

*Вообщем я скачивал игры от alawar,а там ввод вместо привычних "wasd" стрелками,при этом нет настроек управления, и я решил написать код который заменяет буквы 'wasd' на стрелки,но у меня именно  в самой игре программа не работает,а  в других программах да,как это исправить? Сам код:*

```
import pyautogui as ag
import keyboard
import sys
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('W'):
        ag.press('Up')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        ag.press('Down')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('D'):
        ag.press('right')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        ag.press('left')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        print('23d')
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Должно помочь:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):    # <---
        ag.press('up')              # <---
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        ag.press('down')            # <---
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('d'):  # <---
        ag.press('right')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        ag.press('left')
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        print('23d')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Хм,здесь же все то же самое,только с маленькими буквами,там это не имеет разницы,к тому же скрипт везде работает кроме игр которые мне нужны

Comment: @Linkeln я пробовал запустить Ваш скрипт, и у меня не работало с большими буквами. Поэтому я подумал, что в этом Ваша ошибка.